# I made a game in RealityComposer. How can I use this file in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, arkit

I made a game in Reality Composer in iOS. Now I want an app that can run my AR game using Xcode.
How can I do that?

I tried using Reality Kit to generate UI for AR and loading the file.

```
struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        let anchor = try! Experience.Shoots()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
        return arView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
}
```

Its showing error for 'Experience not found in scope'.